# Telegram bot: how to wait for user replies and process them one by one?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to create a telegram bot to predict football scores with my friends. So I have a list of fixtures (e.g. ["Man Utd vs Spurs", "Liverpool vs Man City", "Arsenal vs Chelsea"]).

I want to send these fixtures to a user **one by one**. So it should look like this:

```
user_message: /prediction

bot_message: fixture1
user_message: score1
bot_message: fixture2
user_message: score2
...
bot_message: fixture10
user_message: score10

bot_message: Predictions saved!
```

But I can't understand how to make a bot wait for a user's reply. I tried to use `register_next_step_handler` but it doesn't work as I expected.

```
for fixture in prediction.schedule:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, fixture["fixture_name"])
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, make_prediction)
        ...
```

It firstly sends all the messages (10 in my case) and then executes `make_prediction` function 10 times after just one user message.

This is how it works now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbkYQ.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

**One of solutions:**
I suppose you will store user's predictions somewhere in array
Initially all of user's predictions are empty — filled with *null* value

When user call `/prediction` command, you start end:

1. if there is no null elements in array, goto 7
2. find null element in array
3. ask user to make prediction to this element
4. handle user's answer
5. put answer instead this null
6. goto 1
7. send message that there is no more available predictions

So, to user this dialog will look like this:

```
> /prediction
# Foo vs Bar ?
> Foo
# A vs B ?
> I bet my house to A!
# Thanks for your predictions!
```

Comment: Basically, it doesn't matter how I'm going to save a prediction. It's implemented in ```make_prediction``` function and it puts entries in DynamoDB so far.

The problem is not with "how to store predictions". I can't implement a message by message interaction with the bot (**steps 4 and 6** from your example). So that a user would be able to send predictions in the loop.

Comment: One of solutions: you can store, which handler must be called, when user send his next message. Like: https://pastebin.com/cRgK4B0j